# Does the time I submit or email my job application matter?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, applications

I'm applying to jobs right now and some of my jobs require me to email my resume and cover letter to a specific email. I'm just wondering, would sending my job application at 2am or midnight matter (assuming it's still before the deadline)?

I'm worried about the potential interviewer seeing it and asking themselves why I'm up so late (since people who wake up and do tasks early are seen as responsible I guess). I feel the night time is when I have the most time to sit down and apply.

I'm a student applying for student or new grad positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALmost certainly not.  It is highly unlikely that anyone is going to care whether an application came in at 2am or 2pm.

If you are really concerned, most email programs have the ability to schedule an email to be delivered at a later time.  That would allow you to write an email at 2am and have it delivered at 8am.